# Listen to route change Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to add class to an element whenever route changes, but I cannot use RouterLinkActive and routerLink, I change route on click of a button.

So, I have a sidebar component (which is a part of my layout) where I need to add classes, and I have routes folder where all my router-outlet components are. When I open sidebar, first link (this link has sub elements) opens a component where I have next button which redirects me to next component and a new route and on THAT click, I have to add class to my links sub element. Small explanation:

```
// SIDEBAR
- LINK 1
-- subelement 1
-- subelement 2
-- subelement 3

// LINK 1 COMPONENT
<button (click)="redirectToSublink1()"></button>
```

Subelement 1 opens Subelement 2 and so on. Hope I made it a little more clear whats troubling me.

P.S. Subelements are not links, they are just span elements that need to get class every time route changes.

Comment: check out [router events](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationEnd), but maybe create a plunker as well

Comment: `but I cannot use RouterLinkActive and routerLink`, may I ask why?

Comment: @RobinDijkhof I don't use those elements as links, Those are just text that will show user on which step he is at when he clicks next buttons. Or is there a way of stopping routerLink from navigating?